# How to quickly to find out if a PrestaShop website is version 1.6 or 1.7.x?

Tags: prestashop

While browsing some sites that built on Prestashop, how do you tell if it based on **1.6.x** or **1.7.x**?

Does anyone know the manual approach? Any hints from view source?

Comment: the themes are different

Answer (score 0):

There are many differences between PS 1.6 and PS 1.7 which help you to identify the version.

Some of them are:

### `prestashop` JS var

In PS 1.7 you have a JS variable called `prestashop` which is not in PS 1.6.

### Assets route

In PS you will find CSS assets at `/themes/THEME/css/global.css` while on PS 1.7 they are at `/themes/THEME/assets/css/theme.css`